# Are the column count and column decltypes invariant for the duration of the execution of a SQLite prepared statement?

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

When I look at code other folks have written using the SQLite3 C API, I find `sqlite3_column_decltype` and `sqlite3_column_count` are called from the inner loop (once per result row).

My *understanding* of this database is that these values will never change even if the statement is re-compiled (see [the bit](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) about `sqlite3_prepare_v2`).

So I should be able to call these once and cache them immediately after the call to `sqlite3_prepare`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns' declared types can change, if you use the same statement in two transactions and the database schema is changed between them.
In the same situation, the column count can change, if your query is also using `SELECT *`.

However, a *single* query execution is always inside a transaction ([either a manual or an automatic one](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)).
So if you cache the values after the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` and use them only until the next call to `sqlite3_reset()`/`sqlite3_finalize()`, everything is fine. You can cache them longer if you ensure that all uses are inside the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Return values of both `sqlite3_column_decltype` and `sqlite3_column_count` depend on database schema and the SQL statement.

Yes, you can call these once and cache them after the call to `sqlite3_prepare`.